# Как сделать кликабельное текстовое поле?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть код:

```
<input type="button" 
       name="linkbutton" 
       value="Генерировать ссылку" 
       onclick="generate(this)">
<br>
<input type="text" name="linktext" id="text" size="30">
<sсript language="javascript">
  funсtion generate() {
  var beg = 62000,
      end = 63000,
      val = Math.random() * (end - beg + 1);
  val  = Math.floor(val) + beg;
  link = "http://ссылка/" + val;
  document.getElementById("text").value = link;
}
</script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на текстовое поле "text", в новой вкладке открывалась ссылка, которая в нём прописана?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="ссылка" onclick="window.open(this.value);">
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!